# Which method of SOLR implementation should I use; 3 Questions?

Tags: java, php, mysql, solr

I have a classifieds website which I am now trying to integrate SOLR into, so searches becomes faster...

I have currently Mysql as a db for all my records, and I use PHP to query it and display results.

**I have three main questions:**
If I was to implement SOLR, how is the standard way of doing it?

And, I have not understood if I should update the SOLR index everytime a new classified is posted/or updated/changed, or index them all at once every 12 hours or so?

Should I use SOLR to find the ID of the classifieds and then fetch the record in mysql, or should I use ONLY SOLR?

I need some examples and advice on how to move forward, kindof stuck on this...

I have read some great articles on how to use SOLR with PHP... But haven't found any good articles about dataImportHandlers if that's what I need..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I was to implement SOLR, how is the
>   standard way of doing it?

The standard way to use Solr is to configure it as a separate web application, running in an instance of your favorite web application container (Jetty is recommended, and there may be some incompatibility issues with Resin).  You communicate with it via its HTTP interface, either programmatically using a library like SolrJ or the provided JAR files, or directly using `curl` or a web browser.

To get started, I recommend reading the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html), which is for Solr 1.3 but is for the most part still relevant.

> And, I have not understood if I should
>   update the SOLR index everytime a new
>   classified is posted/or
>   updated/changed, or index them all at
>   once every 12 hours or so?

You can add documents as soon as they are posted.  Solr will first write them into memory and then, depending on your configuration settings, after a certain amount of time has passed or after a certain amount of documents are pending, it will "commit" them to the index on disk.  You can also configure how often the index is optimized, which is an expensive operation that compacts the on-disk index.

> Should I use SOLR to find the ID of
>   the classifieds and then fetch the
>   record in mysql, or should I use ONLY
>   SOLR?

If your data is small (by total size, not individually) you can put it all into Solr, but as it grows larger you may want to use a hybrid solution where Solr just holds the indexed values and MySQL is used for the stored data.

> But haven't found any good articles
>   about dataImportHandlers if that's
>   what I need..

If you want to export your MySQL data into Solr, use the [CSVRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV) (note that csv here can really be any flat file format, like the one MySQL would produce.

**Edit**: in response to your comment, I hadn't looked into `DataImportHandler`s before, but reading the [page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) in the Solr manual, it seems that this is useful for importing data directly from your database (either all at once or periodic deltas) when you have a whole schema that you need to preserve.  So I would say that if the data you need to index is a few fields in a single table, use the `CSVRequestHandler` because it is very easy and does not need to be configured, but if you have a bunch of tables with relationships between them and all of the data needs to be put into the index, then you should look into `DataImportHandler`.

**Edit 2**: anything that can make an HTTP request can update Solr, but here is a [link](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) to a project on google code that provides a PHP implementation of a Solr client.  I have not used it myself.

Comment: Hi danben... Very good answer! I wonder though, do I even need to look into dataImportHandlers? When are they used? Thanks!

Comment: @Camran: thanks for accepting, but why did you remove the upvote?

Comment: I didn't, I accidentally clicked it, and then I couldn't change it back... I will try with another browser! Sorry about that...

Comment: It says I cant change the vote now, too old to be changed... If you could edit your answer and add some text I will upvote it again if possible! Maybe you can answer this: Do you have any examplecode of when PHP updates the SOLR index?

Comment: There, now it worked! Thanks again danben, very much helpful!

Comment: In my case I want to update many documents quite frequently during the day and have the results ready right away. How fast is adding and indexing the newly added document? I will have around 10million documents and I will have maybe 1000updates during one day. Any suggestions? Please also check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247625/apache-solr-adding-editing-deleting-records-frequently

Comment: @danben: I too was stumbling for posts regarding solr integration. Basically I wanted to code modules that enable solr implementation. Similar to what Drupal does: http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr. Would you mind giving me tips in the forms of links/or blogs maybe.